# AWS ELB not serving IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am working with AWS ELB. I mistakenly created another registered target for EC2 instances with another load balancer causing a serving IP on a load balancer to stop working. I had deleted the registered target for EC2 but the serving IP on another load balancer is not still working either. Just wondering is there any way revert back to the former working condition.

Comment: What do you mean by a serving ip? What is your question? It's unclear what you want.

Comment: Adding a Target would not stop the Load Balancer from 'working'. If something is not working for you, then it is a result of the current configuration. You might want to start by checking the Health Check.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.